# Python __add__ magic method with integers

Tags: python, syntax, int, addition, magic-methods

When i am tring this:

```
>>> "a".__add__("b")
'ab'
```

It is working. But this

```
>>> 1.__add__(2)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is not working.
And this is working:

```
>>> 1 .__add__(2) # notice that space after 1
3
```

What is going here? Is it about variable naming rules and is python thinks I am trying to create variable when I am not using space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python parser is intentionally kept dumb and simple. When it sees `1.`, it thinks you are midway through a floating point number, and `1._` is not a valid number (or more correctly, `1.` is a valid float, and you can't follow a value by `_`: `"a" __add__("b")` is also an error). Thus, anything that makes it clear that `.` is not a part of the number helps: having a space before the dot, as you discovered (since space is not found in numbers, Python abandons the idea of a float and goes with integral syntax). Parentheses would also help: `(1).__add__(2)`. Adding another dot does as well: `1..__add__(2)` (here, `1.` is a valid number, then `.__add__` does the usual thing).

Answer (score 2):

The python lexical parser tries to interpret an integer followed by a dot as a floating point number. To avoid this ambiguity, you have to add an extra space.

For comparison, the same code works without problem on a double:

```
>>> 4.23.__add__(2)
6.23
```

It also works if you put the int in parentheses:

```
>>> (5).__add__(4)
9
```

Comment: You can even use two dots in case of floats: `1..__add__(1)`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `1.` the interpreter think you started writing float number (you can see in the IDE (atleast Pycharm) the dot is blue, not white). The space tell it to treat `1.` as a complete number, `1.0`. `1..__add__(2)` will also do the trick.

Comment: To prevent this interpreter behaviour, you may also use explicit typing: `int(1).__add__(2)` or just parentheses `(1).__add__(2)`